# Deploying Django on Apache and WSGI

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Although I have found a bunch of tech support to deploy Django over Apache using WSGI but infact they all have confused me unfortunately, and I couldn't get the Django running. I hope this to be real easy job but being a new comer I am facing difficulties.

I have two Django projects namely website1 and website2 inside my */home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/website1* and *..../website2* dir, respectively. The folder containing settings.py file is *root/* inside the */website1* and */website2* dir.

Apache, mod_wsgi everything is installed as required. How to edit apache2.conf and wsgi.py file to keep these two projects running over port 8080 and 8081?

I am struggling with this issue for past few days and have tried all the following websites.

[link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBMVVruB9Vs),[link2](http://singlas.in/5-step-tutorial-for-using-django-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi/),[link3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/),[link4](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps)

---

UPDATE1:

I have followed the following approach right from the beginning to make things going well but found myself in some new issues. Kindly guide me where I am wrong.

1. Installing mod-wsgi and apache2:
   `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2`
2. Edit the apache2 port to 8083, instead of 80 by altering file "/etc/apache2/ports.conf": `Listen 8083`
3. Add the following line into "/etc/hosts" file: `160.75.133.175 160.75.133.175`
4. Edit the following code in the "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" file:

`<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

5. Create a file inside "/etc/apache2/sites-available/" dir with name "sql_api.conf":

`<VirtualHost *:8083>
    ServerAdmin zia@gmail.com
    ServerName  160.75.133.175
    ServerAlias http://160.75.133.175
    <Directory /home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/ >
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/root/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess  160.75.133.175 user=www-data group=www-data threads=25 python-path=/home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/root/:/usr
    WSGIProcessGroup 160.75.133.175
    ErrorLog /home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/root/error.log
</VirtualHost>`

6. Run the following commands being in "/etc/apache2/sites-available" dir: `sudo a2enmod wsgi && sudo a2ensite sql_api.conf && sudo service apache2 restart`
7. Open `http://160.75.133.175:8083/` but getting the following error:
   *Internal Server Error
   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
   Please contact the server administrator at zia@gmail.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 160.75.133.175 Port 8082*

**NOTE**: When I am making a Django project in */var/www/* dir and then doing the same approach then working just fine! I think because I am trying to access */home/zia/....* dir, there is this issue. Anyways, this is just a guess. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to do. You want to run your production websites on ports 8080 and 8081? Why? Normally you would just use different subdomains.

Comment: I do think that Server Fault would be more appropriate here, no?

Comment: @Daniel: hmm ..... thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably just start over if you made a bunch of changes to your Apache config.  I'm most familiar with setups under Ubuntu.

What you need to look to do is setup both sites under apache as a virtual host.   After installing apache there is a folder called sites-available and sites-enabled they should contain the virtual host files with the names of your website projects.  Each virtual host will point to whereever your .wsgi file is located.  these virtual hosts typically listen under the same port number (as Daniel mentioned above) but serve whichever app is requested based on the domain name.  noobmovies.com google.com ect...

how to setup a virtual host with apache is pretty well explained here.  this assumes you're using ubuntu though.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

your virtual host (the file should be named after your domain exp... noobmovies.com) and will look something like this...

```
**<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin your_admin_email@gmail.com
    ServerName  www.yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias yourdomain.com

    <Directory /home/path/your/project/ >
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/path/your/project/app/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess  yourdomain.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=25 python-path=/path/to/your/project/app/:/path/to/python/virtual/host/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup yourdomain.com
    ErrorLog /path/to/your/app/error.log
</VirtualHost>**
```

keep in mind the WSGIDaemonProcess is only if you're running your app using virtualenv (which you should).   this tells apache where python is that should be used to read the wsgi app/run django app.

So if you're using ubuntu or linux you may just want to uninstall apache and reinstall then just follow the digital ocean instructions to get setup.

Comment: Thx man! Your answer helped me but under a certain situation. When I am making Django project inside /var/www/ dir then everything is working just fine, but since I have my project in a diff /home/zia/... dir, I am running into some issues. Kindly follow my updated question above.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late.  So the problem could be a number of things, but where you will want to look is inside your /var/log/apache2/error.log   this will give you the specific problem that through the server error.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to everyone. Finally found a working procedure. Follow the following steps in order:

1. Installing mod-wsgi and apache2:
   `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2`
2. Edit the apache2 port to 8083, instead of 80 by altering file "/etc/apache2/ports.conf": `Listen 8083`
3. Add the following line into "/etc/hosts" file: `160.75.133.175 160.75.133.175`
4. Edit the following code in the "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" file:

`<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

5. Create a file inside "/etc/apache2/sites-available/" dir with name "sql_api.conf" (make as many .conf files you want with different names, each serving different website):

`<VirtualHost *:8083>
    ServerAdmin zia@gmail.com
    ServerName  160.75.133.175
    ServerAlias http://160.75.133.175
    <Directory /home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/ >
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/root/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess  160.75.133.175 user=www-data group=www-data threads=25 python-path=/home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/root/:/usr
    WSGIProcessGroup 160.75.133.175
    ErrorLog /home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/root/error.log
</VirtualHost>`

6. Add the following lines in the wsgi.py file inside "/home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/root/": `sys.path.append('/home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api/root')
   sys.path.append('/home/zia/Documents/Codes/Django/sql_api')`
7. Run the following commands being in "/etc/apache2/sites-available" dir: `sudo a2enmod wsgi && sudo a2ensite sql_api.conf && sudo service apache2 restart`
8. Open `http://160.75.133.175:8083/`

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!  disregard my last comment.

Comment: This answer, along with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-mod_wsgi-to-serve-applications-on-ubuntu-12-04) helped me immensely with deploying django on an apache web server. Thanks @Zia!